# CSS : Applying Transitions at Breakpoints

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I'm trying to apply transitions to make the media query breakpoints a bit smoother.

On http://maginaire.concept9.ca/ I want to get the logos to resize to smaller/ bigger dimensions and show up in a smoother manner (not jumpy) when getting to screen size under 768px (or other breakpoints). However, I still get the logos being a bit all over the place before the transition is applied - here's an example of what I'm talking about: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfYfSndF54I&feature=youtu.be .

This is the CSS for the logos (applied outside of any media queries since I want it applied at all breakpoints) what I have:

```
logos .project {
-moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out, left 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out, left 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out, left 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out, left 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out, left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

This is the media query for 767px and less:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 767px) {
#logos { margin-left: 0!important; }
#logos .project { float: left!important; width: 100px!important; }
#logos .project, #logos .project:nth-child(2n) { margin-right: 0px!important; }
#logos .project:nth-child(2n+1) { clear: none!important; }
#logos .project:nth-child(4n) { margin-right: 0!important; }
#logos .project:nth-child(4n+1) { clear: both!important; }



.et_pb_portfolio_item { 
float: left;
width: 225px; 
margin: 0px 13px 0px 0 !important; 
    }
```

and for anything above:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
#logos { margin-left: 0!important; }
#logos .project { width: 125px!important; }
#logos .project:nth-child(2n) { margin-right: 60px!important; }
#logos .project:nth-child(2n+1) { clear: none!important; }
#logos .project:nth-child(4n) { margin-right: 0!important; }
#logos .project:nth-child(4n+1) { clear: both!important; }
```

Also verified if without the transitions the logos appear correctly (at 767/768/769px) and I also tried loading it at the end of my css - but no luck :(.

Thanks!!
Dan.

Comment: Could probably do with some more css and html and perhaps an example illustrating the problem. That would help us a lot.

Comment: indeed - added a few more and a video of the problem

Answer (score 0):

So what's happening here is your @media query is kicking in before your animation starts, hence the "the jump". Change the order in which the transition is happening. For example, at 800px start your animation and by the time the browser is resized to 768px your animation is complete and your logos are in place and the transition is smooth.

But i have a question for you. What's the real use of this? let's say I'm viewing your page on my phone, there is no animation which gets rendered on the logo. lil confused there.

Try this.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    if(window.innerWidth < 800){
        //Start the animation here
        //But also make sure the logos go to their respective positions after the animation has been rendered.
    }
}
```

Comment: i know right? pretty pointless, tried to explain to the client I'm doing the site for that visitors will rarely resize the site to th extent it falls under another breakpoint... but he still wants the transitions between breakpoints to be as smooth as possible...

How would I go about doing what you're suggesting? Because the animation itself is only starting once the screen size falls under another media query no?

Comment: Try the code above. I think it should work. But i suggest you try explaining your client that it's a waste of time.